# Telerik RadGrid with MVP Pattern

Tags: c#, gridview, telerik

Does anyone know a solid way of implementing Telerik GridView (or any other grid view for that matter) using the Model-View-Presenter pattern. I have managed to implement some functionality but others just seem almost impossible to implement. This is so especially when working with detail tables because they logic is so tightly integrated with control. One can hardly separate the different concerns. It has made me to almost believe that this cannot be done. But I know there is hope somewhere :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean by "implementing Telerik GridView (or any other grid view for that matter) using the Model-View-Presenter pattern". Can you please clarify? Also denote which Telerik grid you use - AJAX, Silverlight, WPF?